# Are loot drops shared in party, or does everyone gets his own drops?

Tags: path-of-exile

When you're in a party with other players, is loot shared or does everyone gets his own drops? If it's shared, is it free-to-take for everyone, or only for person that landed a killing blow, or perhaps the person who attacked the monsters first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All party members can see all of the drops.  The drops (at least the non-junk stuff) can be flagged with one of the party member's names when it drops.  The player that is flagged on the piece of loot has approximately 3 seconds to loot it before anyone can loot it.

Each loot item will appear, in the world, with a timer bar and the flagged person's name.  If it's not flagged to *you* then it appears in a faded-out color (until the timer expires).

Here's a screen shot showing the timers:

[image]

I snagged the screen shot from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gpjzh7Q4zo0).

Comment: Is the flagging random, or the person that kills the monster gets flagged for the item? Give a little more info about that and I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @ChrisHateZ it's definitely some sort of randomness.  There may be a formula involved though I don't know what it is.  It's not directly tied to who kills the monster.