# Loot sharing system: how does the game assign loot to players?

Tags: path-of-exile

Sometimes, while in a party, *I* open a chest or *I* kill a monster and all [the loot is flagged](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/102862/15726) with one of my friend's name.  Why ?

Comment: Duplicate: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/102858/are-loot-drops-shared-in-party-or-does-everyone-gets-his-own-drops

Comment: It's not the same question; moreover I mentioned the question you are refering to in my own question...

Comment: I rejected the close vote. He really is asking how the game determines whose name gets tagged on a piece of loot initally, which is a dofferent question to the one linked and potentially a different answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check [here](http://www.pathofexile.com/forum/view-thread/392) how it got to the current FFA looting.

In the first page, you can see the official response:

> When an item drops, how do you decide who gets the temporary allocation?
>   **Randomly among nearby players.**

By the way, it's still an open **beta**, so it may change with any patch.